# Find an open set $U$ for which a function $f$ is one to one.

Tags: real-analysis

I was given a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ which is defined as follows:

$f(x,y) = (x+iy)^3$

We look at $\mathbb{C}\;$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $(x,y) = x + iy$

I need to find an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}\;$ for which $f$ is invertible.

We can define $f(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
f_{1}(x,y)=x^{3}-3y^{2}x\\
f_{2}(x,y)=3x^{2}y-y^{3}
\end{array}\right)$ for convinience.

We also have that

$(Df)_{(x,y)}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
3x^{2}-3y^{2} & 6xy\\
-6yx & 3x^{2}-3y^{2}
\end{array}\right],Jf(x,y)=det(Df)_{(x,y)}=9x^{4}+9y^{4}+18x^{2}y^{2}$

How can I find such $U$? I don't really know where to begin. thanks!

Comment: You should really think about what happens in $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take, for instance, $U=\left\{re^{i\theta}\,\middle|\,r>\text{ and }\theta\in\left(0,\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right\}$. Since your map is $z\mapsto z^3$, its restriction to $U$ is injective.

Comment: How can I show that $f$ is one to one on $U$?

Lets say I have $z_{1}=r_{1}e^{i\theta_{1}} , z_{2}=r_{2}e^{i\theta_{2}}\;$ with $ f(z_{1})=f(z_{2})$

$r_1 = r_2\;$ is obvious, however, how do I show that $\theta_1 = \theta_2$?

Comment: Note that$$f(r_1e^{i\theta_1})=f(r_2e^{i\theta_2})\iff r_1^{\,3}e^{3i\theta_1}=r_2^{\,3}e^{3i\theta_2}.$$It is clear then that $r_1=r_2$, as you wrote. So, $e^{3i\theta_1}=e^{3i\theta_2}$, which is equivalent to $e^{3i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}=1$. But then $3i(\theta_1-\theta_2)=2\pi in$, for some integer $n$. Since $\theta_1,\theta_2\in(0,2\pi)$, you can only have $n=0$. In other words, $\theta_1=\theta_2$.

Comment: Thanks.

I chose $U=\left\{ re^{i\theta}\,|\,r>0\text{ and }\theta\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\} =\left\{ x+yi\,|\,x>0,y>0\right\} $ 

I want to use the Inverse function theorem in order to prove that $V=f(U)=\left\{ re^{i\theta}\,|\,r>0\text{ and }\theta\in\left(0,\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\right\} $ is an open set, and that $f^-1$ is continously differentiable, How could I do that?

Comment: That will work also.

Comment: Mind taking a look at my edit?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.